# interpolation of surfaces / fitting surfaces c++ library

Tags: c++, math, 3d, interpolation

I need a library in C/C++ to perform interpolation of surfaces f (x, y) = z. As an alternative to the existing on matlab (e.g. GRIDDATA).
For example: nearest-neighbor, linear, bilinear, bicubic, etc.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[Numerical Recipes](http://www.nr.com/) covers all that stuff, you could always write your own!

Comment: Ths ;) but I prefer a free software solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try [xfarbe](http://www.gnz.mpg.de/gnz/pub/xfarbe_doc.html).

Comment: Ths, the xfarbe looks interesting. I'll try.